# Override Taxonomy Term display with columns showing nodes for each content type

Tags: taxonomy-terms, display-suite

the example is I have 3 node types Brands, Products and Offers asociatted with a vocabulary.
I need to override the taxonomy term display to show the taxonomy term header and then 3 columns with each content type. And the best would be to show fluid columns in order to hide some, for example, when this category has no offers tagged,

I get it work using a display suite layout and adding 3 custom fields, one block views per column for each content type and with a contextual filter depending on the current URL.

*But, after my nice columns, is showing also all the default taxonomy layout. ¿How to hide it?*

**Example:**

Taxonomy header info

Brand1 | Product1 | Offer1

Brand2 | Produtc2 | ----

**etc... and also default taxonomy node listing ....**

Brand1

Brand2

Product1

Procuct2

Offer1

**... that I want to hide.**

thanks
Gustavo

Comment: You want [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), that much I can tell you right now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Find the solutions with Panels overriding system Taxonomy in he Page Manager.